# Search data from two different tables that two tables in different databases

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in different SQL Server databases.

- **Database1** : **table1** (custid, productid, customername )
- **Database2** : **table2** (productname, productid, pice, mfg)

I want to display all the **products purchased** by particular **custid**.

My code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string queryString = "Select custID from Table1 where custId ="+ textbox1.text; 
string TempCustID;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            TempCustID = reader[0].ToString();

            String stringprovider = "@database connection string ";
            Sqlconnection con2 = new sqlconnection(stringprovider);
            Con2.open();
            Cmd2.connection=con2;
            Cmd2.commandType = new commandType.text;
            Cmd2.commandText = "select * from Table2 where Productid = @productid";
            Cmd2.parameters.addwithvalue("@productid",TempCustID);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();

    Dataset Ds = new dataset();
    Oledbdataadaptaer da1 = new oledbdataadapter(cmd2);
    Datatable Table2 = new Data table();
    Da1.fill(table2);
    Datagridview2.source = table2;
}
```

In this I am getting only the first product details of that **customer** it's not displaying all the products at a time.

Comment: You should use the `using` statement for your reader as well. Also your second connection is not disposed either.

Comment: Posting a pe-answered question only makes sense if the question is generic and likely to be of use to other people

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate this into two methods. First will fetch the customer IDs from database one based on the condition. Then pass those customer IDs to second method and fetch the product details. You may create list of customer IDs from first method and build SQL IN clause in second method. Refer
[Building SQL “where in” statement from list of strings in one line?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41880/build-a-string-of-ints-for-sql-where-in)

Answer (score 1):

Change your select statement. join the two tables using `INNER JOIN` with their `productid`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON TABLE2.productid = Table1.productid 
WHERE Table2.productid = @productid
```

That will display all records in two tables, if you want to select specific tables, just remove (*) and replace with the column names you want.

```
SELECT 
    Table1.customername, Table2.productname, Table2.productid, 
    Table2.pice, Table2.mfg 
FROM 
    Table2 
INNER JOIN 
    Table1 ON TABLE2.productid = Table1.productid 
WHERE 
    Table2.productid = @productid
```

Hope my sample code above helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting custID from Table1... Instead of that select productid from Table 1 depending upon customerID

Modify your first query as :

```
string queryString = "Select productid from Table1 where custId ="+ textbox1.text;
```

also command is executing outside the loop...